# Flutter , Cant archive ios in new machine

Tags: xcode, flutter, build, archive

**Hi every one
my application run smoothly with no issue in the IOS simulator (in the new machine) but
when I want to archive my application for testflight ,
this error happened :**

PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
cd /Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9/ios
export ACTION=install
export AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
export ALLOW_TARGET_PLATFORM_SPECIALIZATION=NO
export ALTERNATE_GROUP=staff
export ALTERNATE_MODE=u+w,go-w,a+rX
export ALTERNATE_OWNER=atul
export ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=YES
export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS=NO
export ALWAYS_USE_SEPARATE_HEADERMAPS=NO
export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/AppleInternal/Developer
export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR=/AppleInternal
export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/AppleInternal/Documentation
export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/AppleInternal/Library
export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY=NO
export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES=NO
export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_HEADERS=NO
export ARCHS=arm64
export ARCHS_STANDARD=arm64
export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT=armv7\ arm64
export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT=armv7
export ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT=arm64
export ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT=arm64
export ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS=armv7\ arm64
export ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME=AppIcon
export ASSET_PACK_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/OnDemandResources
export AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS=appletvos\ appletvsimulator\ driverkit\ iphoneos\ iphonesimulator\ macosx\ watchos\ watchsimulator
export AppIdentifierPrefix=3AZGJP929X.
export BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode
export BUILD_ACTIVE_RESOURCES_ONLY=NO
export BUILD_COMPONENTS=headers\ build
export BUILD_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath
export BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=NO
export BUILD_ROOT=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath
export BUILD_STYLE=
export BUILD_VARIANTS=normal
export BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
export BUNDLE_CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH_deep=Contents/
export BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_NAME_deep=MacOS
export BUNDLE_FORMAT=shallow
export BUNDLE_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH=Frameworks
export BUNDLE_PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH=PlugIns
export BUNDLE_PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=PrivateHeaders
export BUNDLE_PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=Headers
export CACHE_ROOT=/var/folders/ky/c2f_xp0d3cv6ryz04mry7fc40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/13.2.1-13C100/Xcode
export CCHROOT=/var/folders/ky/c2f_xp0d3cv6ryz04mry7fc40000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/13.2.1-13C100/Xcode
export CHMOD=/bin/chmod
export CHOWN=/usr/sbin/chown
export CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL=YES
export CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=gnu++0x
export CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY=libc++
export CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES=YES
export CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC=YES
export CLANG_MODULES_BUILD_SESSION_FILE=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
export CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING=YES
export CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION=YES
export CLANG_WARN_COMMA=YES
export CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION=YES
export CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS=YES
export CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE=YES_ERROR
export CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY=YES
export CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION=YES
export CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION=YES
export CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION=YES
export CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION=YES
export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF=YES
export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION=YES
export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS=YES_ERROR
export CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER=NO
export CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS=YES
export CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES=YES
export CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE=YES
export CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE=YES
export CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH=YES
export CLASS_FILE_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-
export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
export DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
export DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
export DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
export DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
export DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE=en
export DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=3AZGJP929X
export DOCUMENTATION_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/en.lproj/Documentation
export DONT_GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE=NO
export DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM=NO
export DSTROOT=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation
export DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME=Runner.app.dSYM
export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT=NO
export DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
export EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME=-iphoneos
export EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=NO
export EMBEDDED_PROFILE_NAME=embedded.mobileprovision
export EMBED_ASSET_PACKS_IN_PRODUCT_BUNDLE=NO
export ENABLE_APP_SANDBOX=NO
export ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
export ENABLE_DEFAULT_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS=YES
export ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME=NO
export ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES=YES
export ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS=NO
export ENABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCES=YES
export ENABLE_PREVIEWS=NO
export ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND=YES
export ENABLE_TESTABILITY=NO
export ENABLE_TESTING_SEARCH_PATHS=NO
export ENTITLEMENTS_ALLOWED=YES
export ENTITLEMENTS_DESTINATION=Signature
export ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED=YES
export EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS=.DS_Store\ .svn\ .git\ .hg\ CVS
export EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES=*.nib\ *.lproj\ *.framework\ *.gch\ *.xcode*\ *.xcassets\ (*)\ .DS_Store\ CVS\ .svn\ .git\ .hg\ *.pbproj\ *.pbxproj
export EXECUTABLES_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/Executables
export EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app
export EXECUTABLE_NAME=Runner
export EXECUTABLE_PATH=Runner.app/Runner
export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=838E985FE3FE0E00E49B9A407E61B249786FE73A
export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME=Apple\ Development:\ Ahmed\ Salam\ (Q7H7R99G4L)
export EXPANDED_PROVISIONING_PROFILE=5d5cdb15-aeed-457a-9ab7-b673981dd70c
export FILE_LIST=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects/LinkFileList
export FIXED_FILES_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/FixedFiles
export FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH=/Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9
export FLUTTER_BUILD_DIR=build
export FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME=0.9.34
export FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER=34
export FLUTTER_ROOT=/Users/atul/Developer/flutter
export FLUTTER_TARGET=lib/main.dart
export FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/Frameworks
export FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX=-framework
export FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos\ \ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FMDB"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Toast"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/flutter_webview_plugin"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/fluttertoast"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/image_gallery_saver"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/image_picker"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/local_auth"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/path_provider_ios"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/permission_handler"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/permission_handler/permission_handler.framework/Headers"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/screen/screen.framework/Headers"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/shared_preferences_ios/shared_preferences_ios.framework/Headers"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/sqflite/sqflite.framework/Headers"\ "/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher_ios/url_launcher_ios.framework/Headers"
export HIDE_BITCODE_SYMBOLS=YES
export HOME=/Users/atul
export ICONV=/usr/bin/iconv
export INDEX_ENABLE_DATA_STORE=NO
export INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS=YES
export INFOPLIST_FILE=Runner/Info.plist
export INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT=binary
export INFOPLIST_PATH=Runner.app/Info.plist
export INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS=NO
export INFOSTRINGS_PATH=Runner.app/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
export INLINE_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS=NO
export INSTALLHDRS_COPY_PHASE=NO
export INSTALLHDRS_SCRIPT_PHASE=NO
export INSTALL_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications
export INSTALL_GROUP=staff
export INSTALL_MODE_FLAG=u+w,go-w,a+rX
export INSTALL_OWNER=atul
export INSTALL_PATH=/Applications
export INSTALL_ROOT=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.0
export JAVAC_DEFAULT_FLAGS=-J-Xms64m\ -J-XX:NewSize=4M\ -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr
export PLATFORM_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
export PLATFORM_DISPLAY_NAME=iOS
export PLATFORM_FAMILY_NAME=iOS
export PLATFORM_NAME=iphoneos
export PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH=arm64
export PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=19C51
export PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT=binary
export PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/PlugIns
export PODS_BUILD_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath
export PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
export PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH=/Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9/ios/.
export PODS_ROOT=/Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9/ios/Pods
export PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates
export PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=YES
export PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/PrefixHeaders
export PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS=NO
export PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/PrivateHeaders
export PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=com.example.maldivesApp
export PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE=APPL
export PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME=Runner
export PRODUCT_NAME=Runner
export PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH=/Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9/ios/Runner/Info.plist
export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application
export PROFILING_CODE=NO
export PROJECT=Runner
export PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/DerivedSources
export PROJECT_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9/ios
export PROJECT_FILE_PATH=/Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
export PROJECT_NAME=Runner
export PROJECT_TEMP_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build
export PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath
export PROVISIONING_PROFILE_REQUIRED=YES
export PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/Headers
export RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLINKS=YES
export REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
export REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
export REMOVE_HEADERS_FROM_EMBEDDED_BUNDLES=YES
export REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
export REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
export RESOURCE_RULES_REQUIRED=YES
export REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/ResourceManagerResources
export REZ_OBJECTS_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
export REZ_SEARCH_PATHS=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos\
export SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES=NO
export SCRIPTS_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/Scripts
export SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT=0
export SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_COUNT=0
export SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT=0
export SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_LIST_COUNT=0
export SDKROOT=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk
export SDK_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk
export SDK_DIR_iphoneos=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk
export SDK_DIR_iphoneos15_2=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk
export SDK_NAME=iphoneos15.2
export SDK_NAMES=iphoneos15.2
export SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=19C51
export SDK_VERSION=15.2
export SDK_VERSION_ACTUAL=150200
export SDK_VERSION_MAJOR=150000
export SDK_VERSION_MINOR=150200
export SED=/usr/bin/sed
export SEPARATE_STRIP=NO
export SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT=NO
export SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP=YES
export SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP=NO
export SHALLOW_BUNDLE=YES
export SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/DerivedSources
export SHARED_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/SharedFrameworks
export SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/PrecompiledHeaders
export SHARED_SUPPORT_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/SharedSupport
export SKIP_INSTALL=NO
export SOURCE_ROOT=/Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9/ios
export SRCROOT=/Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9/ios
export STRINGSDATA_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/undefined_arch
export STRINGSDATA_ROOT=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build
export STRINGS_FILE_INFOPLIST_RENAME=YES
export STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING=binary
export STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES=YES
export STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=YES
export STRIP_STYLE=all
export STRIP_SWIFT_SYMBOLS=YES
export SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES=1,2
export SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS=iphoneos
export SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST=NO
export SUPPORTS_MAC_DESIGNED_FOR_IPHONE_IPAD=YES
export SUPPORTS_TEXT_BASED_API=NO
export SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE=wholemodule
export SWIFT_EMIT_LOC_STRINGS=NO
export SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER=Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h
export SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O
export SWIFT_PLATFORM_TARGET_PREFIX=ios
export SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE_PATH_normal_arm64=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.SwiftFileList
export SWIFT_STDLIB_TOOL_UNSIGNED_DESTINATION_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/SwiftSupport
export SWIFT_VERSION=5.0
export SYMROOT=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath
export SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Utilities
export SYSTEM_APPS_DIR=/Applications
export SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR=/System/Library/CoreServices
export SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR=/Applications/Extras
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built\ Examples
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics\ Tools
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java\ Tools
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance\ Tools
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library/releasenotes
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library/documentation/DeveloperTools
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
export SYSTEM_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/DriverExtensions
export SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/Library/Documentation
export SYSTEM_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
export SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR=/System/Library
export TAPI_VERIFY_MODE=ErrorsOnly
export TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=1
export TARGETNAME=Runner
export TARGET_BUILD_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications
export TARGET_NAME=Runner
export TARGET_TEMP_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build
export TEMP_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build
export TEMP_FILES_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build
export TEMP_FILE_DIR=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build
export TEMP_ROOT=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath
export TEST_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=\ /Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks\ /Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks
export TEST_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS=\ /Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/lib
export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
export TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
export TRACK_WIDGET_CREATION=false
export TREAT_MISSING_BASELINES_AS_TEST_FAILURES=NO
export TREE_SHAKE_ICONS=true
export TeamIdentifierPrefix=3AZGJP929X.
export UID=501
export UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app
export UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT=NO
export USER=atul
export USER_APPS_DIR=/Users/atul/Applications
export USER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Users/atul/Library
export USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC=YES
export USE_HEADERMAP=YES
export USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS=NO
export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES=YES
export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_CLANG=YES
export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_LD=YES
export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_TAPI=YES
export USE_RECURSIVE_SCRIPT_INPUTS_IN_SCRIPT_PHASES=YES
export VALIDATE_DEVELOPMENT_ASSET_PATHS=YES_ERROR
export VALIDATE_PRODUCT=YES
export VALIDATE_WORKSPACE=YES_ERROR
export VALID_ARCHS=arm64\ arm64e\ armv7\ armv7s
export VERBOSE_PBXCP=NO
export VERSIONING_SYSTEM=apple-generic
export VERSIONPLIST_PATH=Runner.app/version.plist
export VERSION_INFO_BUILDER=atul
export VERSION_INFO_FILE=Runner_vers.c
export VERSION_INFO_STRING="@(#)PROGRAM:Runner\ \ PROJECT:Runner-35"
export WATCHKIT_2_SUPPORT_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/WatchKitSupport2
export WATCHKIT_SUPPORT_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/WatchKitSupport
export WRAPPER_EXTENSION=app
export WRAPPER_NAME=Runner.app
export WRAPPER_SUFFIX=.app
export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES=NO
export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR=/Users/atul/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=13C100
export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL=1321
export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR=1300
export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR=1320
export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/XPCServices
export YACC=yacc
export arch=undefined_arch
export variant=normal
/bin/sh -c /Users/atul/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hguloymvswupclfilphdbfwcxpfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh

**Failed to package /Users/atul/Desktop/scsoftindia-fluttermobileapp-efe0b9a923e9.**
**Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Distribution methods range from exporting your app for test devices to uploading it to App Store Connect. You can useTestFlight to distribute iOS, tvOS, and watchOS beta builds to testers and collect feedback. If you want to distribute your app to registered devices, to beta testers using TestFlight, or through the App Store, you need to join the Apple Developer Program. Apple creates an App Store Connect account for you and you can start uploading builds.